# Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones. Yet again

Tags: modeling, animation

I tried many things and I am out of my options. I need just make a simple hand movement can't add automatic weighting because of that error

https://we.tl/t-y5iKQCIma4

I put the file in we transfer if someone wants to help me out.

Comment: Scale mesh and armature up tenfold, apply scale, autoweight; optionally, scale down to one-tenth, apply scale.  But mesh isn't good candidate for autoweights anyways because of non-manifold mesh, multiple mesh components.

Comment: so what i need to do to save this,or give me an advice to what to do, i am new to this and is hard and what you said earlier i dont know how to do it yet like i said i am a biginer thx for the reply you are kind!

Comment: You need to look at some tutorials on weight painting, and you need to google "non manifold mesh" and read all you can about it.

Comment: i tryed to scale it up and it worked but my hand left untouched and move to the origine of the world and the armature remains still

Comment: how can i save then the model with light on the hand and everything and making it to work?to restart and make a hand with low count mesh objects?

Comment: First, do your research (including the research I mentioned above, and including searching for answers on SE); then, play with it a little to develop your understanding; then if you still don't have it, spend a little bit of time organizing your thoughts and ask a new SE question, because your new questions are out of scope of the question you originally asked.

Comment: i manage to solve it,the problems where 2 the ring objects from my hand i removed them and now everything work just fine thx for the info and help thx a lot